# How to check difference between 2 numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm developing VBA which should compare 2 numbers for difference and trying to find way to do most efficient.

Tried to inspect which number is higher than deduct smaller number and check for difference between this 2 numbers.

This number `param_1` 0.543729495662964 to compare with this number `param_2` 0.304649054452729 and show difference in this case difference = 0.2390804412

Or `param_1` 0.543729495662964 with `param_2` 0.599799256372803 and store difference between this two numbers

Then continue with program.

Numbers can't be higher than 1.0 first number(param_1) is static and not changing. param_2 is number which can be higher or lower than param_1 and this is gives me a lot of trouble.

Comment: look into `ABS()` it then does not matter which is higher than the other.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner its actually works for me.